# SQL Server: return all rows in table and read their values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table with 6 columns and 5 rows. I want to select all rows and read through them using the `SqlDataReader` (ASP.NET C#). I currently can access single columns using `dataReader["columnName"].ToString()` and store that in a string variable.

I want to read through the columns row by row.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried? Use the `dataReader.Read()` with a while loop and then index each column in the current row by an index or columnName in a `for` loop. Here's the MSDN page for Read(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Using an **ORM** like Dapper.NET or Entity Framework, you wouldn't have to fiddle around with all those very boring, very error-prone low-level code at all - they would handle all those messy details for you, and just return a nice, usable .NET objects (or a list of objects) to you.....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to store the rows and columns into a collection of some sort, you can try using a List and Dictionary which will let you add as many rows as you need.

```
     List<Dictionary<string, string>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
     Dictionary<string, string> column; 
     string sqlQuery = "SELECT USER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM USERS";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {    //Every new row will create a new dictionary that holds the columns
             column = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

             column["USER_ID"] = reader["USER_ID"].ToString();
             column["FIRSTNAME"] = reader["FIRSTNAME"].ToString();
             column["LASTNAME"] = reader["LASTNAME"].ToString();

             rows.Add(column); //Place the dictionary into the list
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
         //If an exception occurs, write it to the console
         Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }

    //Once you've read the rows into the collection you can loop through to                     
    //display the results

    foreach(Dictionary<string, string> column in rows)
    {
        Console.Write(column["USER_ID"]) + " ";
        Console.Write(column["FIRSTNAME"] + " ";
        Console.Write(column["LASTNAME"] + " ";
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on an [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), here's a straightforward implementation:

```
    private static void ReadGetOrdinal(string connectionString)
    {
        string queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    // Call GetOrdinal and assign value to variable. 
                    int customerID = reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerID");

                    // Use variable with GetString inside of loop. 
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CustomerID={0}", reader.GetString(customerID));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should put the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into `using(...) { ... }` blocks as well !

Comment: Quite right @marc_s. Also meaning the `reader.Close()` becomes redundant

Answer (score 3):

Here you go,

Member Variables:

```
static SqlConnection moConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX");
static SqlCommand moCommand = new SqlCommand();
static SqlDataAdapter moAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
static DataSet moDataSet = new DataSet();
static string msQuery;
```

In class method, you have to write below code:

```
DataSet loDataSet = new DataSet();
msQuery = "SELECT * FROM [TableName]";
Execommand(msQuery);
moAdapter.Fill(loDataSet);
DataTable loTable = new DataTable();
loTable = loDataSet.Tables[0];
if (loTable != null && loTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow foRow in loTable.Rows)
    {
       string lsUserID = Convert.ToString(foRow["UserID"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of you for helping out. I am answering this to reflect my experience. I used GridView which is a standard control of ASP.NET. It really does the job easily and highly customizable.

a sample code has been added below for further illustration of how it works. If anyone requires help when using it, feel free to post here and I will try my best to help

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID"   
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">  
        <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True"   
                SortExpression="CustomerID" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName"   
                SortExpression="CompanyName" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName"   
                SortExpression="ContactName" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle"   
                SortExpression="ContactTitle" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address"   
                SortExpression="Address" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region"   
                SortExpression="Region" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode"   
                SortExpression="PostalCode" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country"   
                SortExpression="Country" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax" />  
        </Columns>  
    </asp:GridView>
```