# SQL Query only returns one row , when I try Get All rows from table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the MVC 5 and I have a page where you can update the blogs but when I try Get All rows or Get All Blogs from table (relative to Update Blog) , its just returns only the first row ,Even I have 4 row in table.Can someone please point me in the right direction?

The code in The Fac :

```
 public class AutoFac<T> where T : new()
 {
private string table;
private Mapper<T> mapper = new Mapper<T>();

public T GetAlle()
        {
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table, Conn.CreateConnection()))
            {
                var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                T type = new T();

                if (r.Read())
                {
                    type = mapper.Map(r);
                }

                r.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                return type;
            }

        }
}
```

The Code in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateBlog()
        {
            return View(bf.GetAlle());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateBlog(Blog b)
        {

            bf.Update(b);
            ViewBag.MSG = "Blog is updated now";
            return View();
        }
```

The Code in the View:

```
@model BlogRep.Blog

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UpdateBlog";
}

<h2>UpdateBlog</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <h4>Blog</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.HiddenFor(model =>model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Overskrift, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Overskrift, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tekst, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tekst, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dato, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />

            </div>
            @ViewBag.MSG
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: return all rows in table and read their values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056649/sql-server-return-all-rows-in-table-and-read-their-values)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the Fac should be like this

```
public class AutoFac<T> where T : new()
{
    private string table;
    private Mapper<T> mapper = new Mapper<T>();

    public T[] GetAlle()
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table, Conn.CreateConnection()))
        {
            var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<T> type = new List<T>();

            while(r.Read())
            {
                type.Add(mapper.Map(r));
            }

            r.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            return type.ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

You can change your view like this

```
@model BlogRep.Blog[]

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UpdateBlog";
}

<h2>AllBlogs</h2>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="headeralign" data-sortable="true">Overskrift</th>
                    <th class="headeralign" data-sortable="true">Tekst</th>
                    <th class="headeralign" data-sortable="true">Dato</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">@item.Overskrift</td>
                        <td align="center">@item.Tekst</td>
                        <td align="center">@item.Dato</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: tnx for you comment, should i also change my View !! , when i using List is that correct ?! bcz , i just change the fac and than i get this error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'BlogRep.Blog[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BlogRep.Blog'.

Comment: yes you need to change the view also as you will get array

Comment: i just used foreach , but is still returns one row !

Comment: and again,its just returns one row :(

Comment: no buddy it should give the list of all records, check the db once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143683/discussion-between-supraj-v-and-man-down).